# Drop Pin on Default Google Maps from My App in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps

i have an address for a location. when i click some button in my app. it should redirect to default google map in android and drop the pin to that particular location. how to do that? Any Idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html) describes the various `Intents` that the Google Maps application will respond to, if it exists on a given device. You will presumably want a `geo:0,0?q=my+street+address` `Uri` on an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`.

Comment: is this possible in emulator?

Comment: can you tell me the syntax plz. i cant do that.

Comment: `"geo:0,0?q=my+street+address"` is a String, where you replace `my+street+address` with your address in URL-encoded form. You use `Uri.parse()` to turn it into a `Uri`. You pass that as the second parameter to an Intent constructor that take `ACTION_VIEW` as the first parameter. You wrap all of that in a `startActivity()` call. See http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Activities/Launch/ for a sample project (but one that uses the latitude/longitude form of the `Uri`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I did it using a "**View on map**" button. Posting here to help others in need because It took me the whole day to figure it out:

http://randroidblog.blogspot.com/2012/01/view-on-map-activity.html