# Drop pin in MapView

Tags: android, maps, android-maps

I readed this:
[Drop Pin on Default Google Maps from My App in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683287/drop-pin-on-default-google-maps-in-android)
and do all the same.
But there is no pin droped on the map, after i call:
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));

The map centered on that uri-location, but no any pin dropped on the map.

So, there is a question:
How to drop pin on the map?

Comment: hey can you show me what you have done? its working cool for me man.

Comment: prev_geo_uri = Uri.parse("geo: "+prevLocation.getLatitude()+","+prevLocation.getLongitude());
      startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,prev_geo_uri));

Comment: [Here][1] is Complete code of DragAndDrop on MapView in android


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897409/how-does-one-implement-drag-and-drop-for-android-marker/11629199#11629199

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add something to search for too (the q param).  If all you have is a lon/lat, specify it twice as below:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:36.4248,-5.14495?z=14&q=36.4248,-5.14495"); 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Note that the z parameter is optional.

You can also label the pin by adding it in brackets after the q's lon i.e.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:36.4248,-5.14495?z=14&q=36.4248,-5.14495(My+pin+label)"); 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
startActivity(intent);
```