# Android MapView draggable marker

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I would like to create a draggable marker in Android MapView (com.google.android.maps.MapView), exactly like this: http://koti.mbnet.fi/ojalesa/exam/draggable.html.

I've already got an overlay pointing to the location I want, but I'd like the marker icon to be draggable like in the above example. Is there something ready to use for this or is it necessary to implement the dragging logic myself?

Comment: Check my post HERE
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897409/how-does-one-implement-drag-and-drop-for-android-marker

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to implement the dragging yourself. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkTouch/) demonstrating drag and drop of an `OverlayItem` from an `ItemizedOverlay`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, is the drag&drop basically implemented by the onTouchEvent on your source code? Thank you