# how can a Google Map with draggable marker work (drag marker) on mobile browser touch screens?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, draggable, marker

In a desktop browser it all works well using a mouse click drag and drop but not for touch screens. What will I need to do to enable the drag of a marker in mobile (tablet & phone) browsers?

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                mapOptions);
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
   window.setTimeout(function() {
      map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
     }, 3000);
  }); 


        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map:map,
          draggable: true,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          position: parliament,
          icon: psrimage
        });
```

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238530/android-mapview-draggable-marker

Comment: Sorry but it is NOT a duplicate. When I load the above page on my android tablet I cannot drag the draggable marker, can you?

Comment: Also I am not using the Android Google com.google.android.maps.MapView, this system is working perfectly in a normal browser (non touch)

Comment: I have noticed that the drag feature works well on my iphone in the browser but not on my android tablet. Any ideas as to how I can it functioning 1n the android browser?