# Reverse Geocoding in Android : Error "IOException:Service not Available"

Tags: android, android-maps, reverse-geocoding

1. My app is totally based on maps. The requirement is user need to enter the source and destination in words then i need to draw the route on map with those values with markers. Later on the displayed map with route drawn, the user able to change/modify the source or destination by dragging the marker which are displayed. Simultaneously the route drawn should also change dynamically with user's action.
2. I can get the lat & long from the map using `onTouchEvent`. But in the same map not able to set both source and destination.
3. And i tried reverse geocoding to get the lat & lon from given location names. But i get `IOException:Service not Available`. I was searching for solution, then i found this [link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816) which started in jun 2010, still no fix for this bug till now.

Please help.Also provide sample code.

Thanks.

Comment: Since 5 hrs i get no help!!! Is my question having anything wrong?.

Comment: no its not like that, people are here from different timezone so it happens that when you asked the question the user online have no idea about that, okay anyways tell me you running your app in Emulator?? if yes then it wont work, you will need to test in real device to check output of GEOCODING classes.

Comment: @MKJParekh, Thanks for the help. I got answer for only the third case.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by `got answer for only the third case.`

Comment: i edited by adding numbers,now find number 3. You answer is for only 3rd one. Now waiting for 1 and 2. I hope you got it know.

Comment: use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897409/how-does-one-implement-drag-and-drop-for-android-marker