# touch the screen and add a marker in android

Tags: android, coordinates, marker, osmdroid

I want add a marker when I touch the screen. I use osmdroid and no google map.
Moreover, I want get back coordinate of this marker.

for the moment, I can display the osm map and display the location of the user.

thanks !

Comment: I found a Link maybe this one will helps u 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897409/how-does-one-implement-drag-and-drop-for-android-marker

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991175/osmdroid-ontap-example

Answer (score 0):

You can use MapEventsReceiver.
First make sure you have

```
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:6.1.6'
```

in your build gradle (or newer version).
Then you make you OSMDroid class implement it

```
public class OSMapClass implements MapEventsReceiver {

// Your map implementation here

    @Override
    public boolean singleTapConfirmedHelper(GeoPoint p) {
    // Here implement single click behaviour
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean longPressHelper(GeoPoint p) {
    // Here implement long click behaviour
        return false;
    }
}
```