# Make marker draggable after single click in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, draggable, google-maps-markers

I am doing a little project on Android with Google maps. And I have one question - it is possible to make marker draggable with single click on it, not after long press. For example: I click marker, it changes icon and I can drag it anywhere in map, and then after another tap he will not be draggable again and changes its icon back? (Marker must be draggable all the time from first tap to second even if you release it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@user2595870:

Hello,

I know it should be in comment but due to less reputations i am suggesting you in answer.

You want to `drag and drop` facility for `marker` kind of thing ?

if so there is good example provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897409/how-does-one-implement-drag-and-drop-for-android-marker). Please check it.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is not fpr API2, but i got the idea, and now everything works fine.

Comment: @Eddwhis Hi, please tell us how you did it, I've struggling for days to figure this out. We want to implement it for v2

Comment: I was using `dispatchtouchevent` function and moving marker by screen coordinates, getting LatLng from `GoogleMap.getProjection()`.

Comment: @Eddwhis Do you have the source code for how you solved this please? :)