# Android google map drag drop marker on single click on marker

Tags: android, google-maps, drag-and-drop, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using Google Map API v2.

In this I place a draggable marker on map.

To drag marker I need to long press on marker for some seconds and then after drag event triggers and dragging is possible.

I want that drag event be called single tap to marker.

How to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: did you find any thing ?

Answer (score -2):

You can use onTouchListener instead onLongClickListener. Start dragging as soon as touch is detected and stop when touch is completed.

Hope this thread can help you in some way. You can get the idea from this.

[Make marker draggable after single click in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725835/make-marker-draggable-after-single-click-in-android)

There is another workaround for this. You can move map under the marker. Marker will remain in the center and the map will move

Comment: But what is startDragging function here ?

Comment: How to start/stop dragging via code. Because normally in google maps we have to simply override onMarkerdrag function defined in API.

Comment: I wrote startDragging just for example.

Comment: But what will be this startDragging fn ? Thats what my question is?

Comment: start dragging the marker and when touch is completed marker is moved to the new coordinates.startDragging is like onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

    } and stopDragging is onMarkerDragEnd

Comment: The link provided in the answer relates to old Google Maps V1. It is useless for V2.