# Android Google Maps api v2 Radius Circle Draggable

Tags: android, google-maps, geometry

I am using Google Maps V2 Api to Retrieve Maps in my App, Whenever Location Changes the Circle is drawn with radius 5km and using Places Api to find some places like ATM,BANK and it will Mark the places with Markers. Its working good.

Like this
[image]

My requirement is  Circle with dragging to be implemented like Marker Dragging.

Searched many sites about this and not clear in it, any help will be appreciated..

Comment: I am not clear, issue in Circle with dragging ? OR you dont know anything ?

Comment: Circle is working, but dragging method i dont know to implement. @Prince

Comment: We can not see anything is working. What did you do? Pls make your question clear.

Comment: @BatuhanC see the edit the picture added is what i have now and that circle need to be dragging compatibility.. how to implement.

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible. You want to drag and drop an item from mapfragment. It is not a normal image.

Comment: That Circle is not in Mapfragment, i included using the CircleOptions class and Circle class.. @BatuhanC

Comment: [Link-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897409/how-does-one-implement-drag-and-drop-for-android-marker) and [Link-2](http://www.lynda.com/Android-tutorials/Dragging-dropping-markers/133347/144386-4.html?vid=6&fatoc=1) . Maybe, you can start from this links about the marker dragging and dropping.

Comment: @BatuhanC i dont want a marker dragging implementation.. i already did that, instead that circle should be able to drag and drop..

Comment: Just some hints, which may help: a) you need to detect, whether a touch is inside the circle or outside. b) if inside the circle, you have to follow the touchevent while its moving, and just adapt the position of the circle using Circle.setCenter(latLngOfTouchPoint)

Comment: My ques is how can i move the circle like drag and drop if the circle touched inside? i need to touch the circle and move the circle with fingers(in device) or pointers(in emulator) @user2808624

Comment: I am not sure, what you are exactly looking for. There is no out-of-the-box solution. You will have to intercept the touch events, check whether the touch is inside the circle, and adapt the circle center, while the touch is moving. But this is of course quite a bit of hand-coding.

Comment: hey i have pretty similar requirements did you able to solve it?